# Color paths in d3.layout.tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I want to color paths in my collapsible d3 layout based on one the node directly above the lowest level.  Obviously there will only be different colors when more then one of the nodes directly above the child node is expanded.

I am using the code from the d3js example with only minor modifications:

```
function buildTree(data) {
        var margin = {top: 20, right: 120, bottom: 20, left: 120},
                width = 960 - margin.right - margin.left,
                height = 800 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
        var i = 0,
                duration = 750,
                root;
        var tree = d3.layout.tree()
                .size([height, width]);
        var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
                .projection(function (d) {
                    return [d.y, d.x];
                });
        var svg = d3.select("#node").append("svg")
                .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
                .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
                .append("g")
                .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
        root = data;
        root.x0 = height / 2;
        root.y0 = 0;
        function collapse(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d._children.forEach(collapse);
                d.children = null;
            }
        }
        root.children.forEach(collapse);
        update(root);
        d3.select(self.frameElement).style("height", "800px");
        function update(source) {
            // Compute the new tree layout.
            var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse(),
                    links = tree.links(nodes);
            // Normalize for fixed-depth.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                d.y = d.depth * 180;
            });
            // Update the nodes…
            var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
                    .data(nodes, function (d) {
                        return d.id || (d.id = ++i);
                    });
            // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
            var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node")
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")";
                    })
                    .on("click", click);
            nodeEnter.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", 1e-6)
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                    });
            nodeEnter.append("text")
                    .attr("x", function (d) {
                        return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10;
                    })
                    .attr("dy", "1em")
                    .attr("text-anchor", function (d) {
                        return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start";
                    })
                    .text(function (d) {
                        return d.name;
                    })
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
            // Transition nodes to their new position.
            var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")";
                    });
            nodeUpdate.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 4.5)
                    .style("fill", function (d) {
                        return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff";
                    });

            nodeUpdate.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1);
            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")";
                    })
                    .remove();
            nodeExit.select("circle")
                    .attr("r", 1e-4);
            nodeExit.select("text")
                    .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);
            // Update the links…
            var link = svg.selectAll("path.link")
                    .data(links, function (d) {
                        return d.target.id;
                    });
            // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
            link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                    .attr("class", "link")
                    .attr("d", function (d) {
                        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                    });
            // Transition links to their new position.
            link.transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", diagonal);
            // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
            link.exit().transition()
                    .duration(duration)
                    .attr("d", function (d) {
                        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
                        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                    })
                    .remove();
            // Stash the old positions for transition.
            nodes.forEach(function (d) {
                d.x0 = d.x;
                d.y0 = d.y;
            });
        }
        // Toggle children on click.
        function click(d) {
            if (d.children) {
                d._children = d.children;
                d.children = null;
            } else {
                d.children = d._children;
                d._children = null;
            }
            update(d);
        }
    }
```

The "link" colors (which is what I want to change) are coming from some defined styles:

```
    .node {
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    .node circle {
        fill: #fff;
        stroke: steelblue;
        stroke-width: 2px;
    }

    .node text {
        font: 12px sans-serif;
        fill: white;
    }

    .link {
        fill: none;
        stroke: white;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
```

I am on a black background so I would like to keep the colors to red, green, blue, white, etc (those that can be seen against black).

Answer (score 2):

You can color the links dynamically by setting the stroke color in the code. The depth of a node (which, if I'm understanding correctly is what you're after) is part of its data so you can reference it directly.

```
var color = d3.scale.category20();
// ...
link.transition()
    .duration(duration)
    .attr("d", diagonal)
    .style("stroke", function(d) { return color(d.source.depth); });
```

Comment: yup, that makes sense.  I'll give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

You can set the `link` colors when they are getting created, here in the code:

```js
       link.enter().insert("path", "g")
                .attr("class", "link")
                .attr("d", function (d) {
                    var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
                    return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
                })
                .attr("stroke", function (d) { return 'blue'; }) 
                               // ^^ return your color here.
```

And you can then safely remove the CSS definition for the `stroke` of `.link`.

Comment: you directly cannot add `stroke` as attribute it has to come via style

Comment: @GovindMantri both .attr and .style will work, though I agree that it should be probably done using .style